# When using flock to check if another process is running, sometimes the file is used by MySQL process

Tags: php, mysql

I use PHP function flock to check if another process is running, but sometimes the file is used by MySQL process. This is the result for lsof command :

[image]

And this is my php script:

```
$list = [];
$handle_list = fopen("$backup path/log/list.txt", "a+");
if(flock($handle_list, LOCK_EX | LOCK_NB))
{
    while(($buffer = fgets($handle_list, 4096)) !== false)
    {
        $buffer = str_replace(["\r", "\n"], '', $buffer);
        $list[] = $buffer;
    }
}
else
{
    echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s'). " : ERROR : Another process running\n\n\n";
    exit(-1);
}
```

Without MySQL process locking the file, the script work fine. I don't know when can MySQL use a file?

Comment: Are you sure that's not the log file MySQL would write to?

Comment: Hi @apokryfos
You see the path, it's a file that i have created to be used just by my script php, that why I'm confused.
But before, I synchronize this file with another server using rsync command.
MySQL didn't do a change in the file, but just by using it, flock don't work

Comment: Well, mysqld is clearly holding it so maybe you have added it somewhere to your configuration? Another reason might be that mysqld might lock everything in that directory if it is a special directory

Comment: Please don't use image to show your php code. Copy the code to your question instead.

Comment: Hi, there are no problem with the php code, I will copy the code next time, it's a code that you can find it in PHP documentation, and also there other files in the directory and the didn't used by MySQL ?!!

Comment: I thought that maybe the cause is the name _list_ or something that I don't know about MySQL, Now I have changed the solution to check the PID.

Comment: What I do see in the path is the word DB which implies you do some database stuff in there. Your code doesn't seem to show any of that.

Comment: No, in my code, i just check for mysql status exec("service mysql status") and start or stop mysql service depend on it.
If no one have the some problem, (with other files for example) then it's OK. i used flock often and this is my first time I see mysql use a file that has nothing to do with it.